# How to define and run capistrano 3 task after deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

I have a capistrano script that works perfect, except it's not running a task after the deploy. I'm using rails_daemons to launch the rails application and a I need to restart the daemons.

*#deploy.rb*

```
namespace :deploy do
  on roles :all do
    execute :bundle, "exec rake daemons:restart"
  end
end
```

Tryed this also:

```
task :restart_daemons, :roles => :app do
  execute :bundle, "exec rake daemons:restart"
end

after "deploy", "deploy:restart_daemons"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, have you checked if `bundle exec rake daemons:restart` works locally? If so, try something like this:

```
namespace :deploy do

  after :restart do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      within release_path do
         execute :rake, 'daemons:restart'
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Got this as an error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2+)`

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos so the problem must be in the task's definition, rather than in your capistrano configuration

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this one (Rails 7/Capistrano 3)

In `config/deploy/production.rb`

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'sitemap.xml refresh'
  task :sitemap_refresh do
    on roles(:app) do
      within current_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, 'sitemap:refresh'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  after 'deploy', 'deploy:sitemap_refresh'
end
```